# How do you inject an object into a singleton?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, singleton

I've got a singleton class:

```
public class Widget
{
    private Mapper mapper;

    private static Widget SINGLETON;

    private Widget(Mapper map)
    {
        setMapper(map);
    }

    public Widget getInstance()
    {
        if(SINGLETON == null)
            SINGLETON = new Widget(???);

        return SINGLETON;
    }
}
```

Not only do I not understand how to pass `SINGLETON` a `Mapper` in its private constructor, I'm not seeing how I can use dependency injection to properly set the singleton up. Say `Mapper` is an interface. Perhaps under "normal" execution I want to pass `SINGLETON` a `StandardMapper` instance, but while unit testing, I want to pass it a `MockMapper`.

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Comment: Singletons are the disease; dependency injection is the cure. Use your DI container to control lifetime and get rid of the singleton.

Comment: @TrueWill - I'd agree with your comment if you said factory instead of singleton.

Comment: @Perception - factories still have their uses, especially factory delegates (in .NET). It's handy to inject a method pointer that will create objects implementing an interface on demand. Singletons - they were born bad, and they never die.

Comment: @TrueWill - I won't speak to .NET, but as far as Java goes DI was invented to solve the problem of rampant, runaway factories. I think you are confusing the two because most factories were implemented using a Singleton pattern.

Comment: @Perception - DI was invented to solve the problem of high coupling. DI containers are a partial replacement for factories. Singletons introduce coupling. I am not confusing the two.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6944/discussion-between-perception-and-truewill)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass an argument to `getInstance()`, perhaps providing one with and without a `Widget`.

If you're using a DI framework there are other options, but you don't mention what you're doing. There would be several AOP options as well, but ultimately you'll still have to decide how to indicate what `Widget` implementation to use.

*(Minor nit, you're not "injecting a singleton", you're injecting **into** a singleton.)*

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do to inject into a Singleton.

```
public enum Widget {
    SINGLETON;

    private Mapper mapper;

    public void setMapper(Mapper mapper) { this.mapper = mapper; }
}
```

If you are going to inject this singleton somewhere I would make it implement an interface

```
public enum Widget implement IWidget {
```

This way the singleton can be mocked as required provided you only use its interface.

Answer (score 0):

In this instance you will have to make `Mapper` a parameter of `getInstance`

The other alternative is getting an instance of `Mapper` from some sort of repository, or another static `getInstance` method which is the first step on the long road to an untestable application.